# insert missing row in table oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in table like below:

```
Primary_id  Serial_ID   PRIMARY_ID  SECONDARY_ID    queue_ID
1   100 58  89  Q1428291
2   100 58  89  Q1428281
3   100 58  89  Q1428293
4   100 89  58  Q1428293
5   100 89  58  Q1428291
6   100 89  58  Q1428000281
7   200 16  28  Q1433144
8   200 16  28  Q1431953
9   200 16  28  Q1432397
10  200 16  28  Q1431921
11  200 28  16  Q1433144
12  200 28  16  Q1432397
13  200 28  16  Q1431921
```

We have primary_ID and Secondary_ID column. for serial_ID 100 we have 3 primary and 3 secondary records ..If you see the data Primary_ID become secondary and secondary become primary(3 each).but for serial_id 200 we have 4 primary records but 3 secondry records..

I want to insert missing record in the table.For ex serial_id 200 has missing data for primary ID 28 so insert this into table.Please assist

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: Define a "missing record". What should the queue_id be for that ? For serial_id 100 there are 4 different queue_id values ...

Comment: Q1428000281 is given by mistake it should be Q1428281

Comment: Primary_id  Serial_ID   PRIMARY_ID  SECONDARY_ID    queue_ID
1   100 58  89  Q1428291
2   100 58  89  Q1428281
3   100 58  89  Q1428293
4   100 89  58  Q1428293
5   100 89  58  Q1428291
6   100 89  58  Q1428281
7   200 16  28  Q1433144
8   200 16  28  Q1431953
9   200 16  28  Q1432397
10  200 16  28  Q1431921
11  200 28  16  Q1433144
12  200 28  16  Q1432397
13  200 28  16  Q1431921

Comment: missing record should have entry like this

Comment: insert into test values (14,  200, 28  ,16 , 'Q1431953')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this. In the temp_table, I put rows into two different types ('P' or 'S').

I assume that the queue_id = 'Q1428000281' (from row 6) is a mistake, and It should be 'Q1428281'.

```sql
drop table table_test ;
create table table_test (id, serial_id, primary_id, secondary_id, queue_id) as (
select 1 ,  100, 58,  89,  'Q1428291'       from dual union all
select 2 ,  100, 58,  89,  'Q1428281'       from dual union all
select 3 ,  100, 58,  89,  'Q1428293'       from dual union all
select 4 ,  100, 89,  58,  'Q1428293'       from dual union all
select 5 ,  100, 89,  58,  'Q1428291'       from dual union all
select 6 ,  100, 89,  58,  'Q1428000281'    from dual union all
select 7 ,  200, 16,  28,  'Q1433144'       from dual union all
select 8 ,  200, 16,  28,  'Q1431953'       from dual union all
select 9 ,  200, 16,  28,  'Q1432397'       from dual union all
select 10,  200, 16,  28,  'Q1431921'       from dual union all
select 11,  200, 28,  16,  'Q1433144'       from dual union all
select 12,  200, 28,  16,  'Q1432397'       from dual union all
select 13,  200, 28,  16,  'Q1431921'       from dual
)
;

insert into table_test (id, serial_id, primary_id, secondary_id, queue_id)
with temp_table as (
select t.*
    , case when primary_id < secondary_id then 'P' else 'S' end type_t
from table_test t
)
select v_max.id_max + rownum ID, SERIAL_ID, PRIMARY_ID, SECONDARY_ID, queue_id
from (
  select SERIAL_ID
    , max(SECONDARY_ID) PRIMARY_ID
    , min(PRIMARY_ID) SECONDARY_ID
    , max(queue_id)queue_id
    , count(TYPE_T) cnt
  from temp_table tp
  group by SERIAL_ID
    , least(PRIMARY_ID, SECONDARY_ID)
    , greatest(PRIMARY_ID, SECONDARY_ID)
    , QUEUE_ID
  having count(TYPE_T) != 2
)t 
cross join (select max(id) id_max from table_test) v_max
;
```

Comment: ID 8 entry is missing so we need to insert new entry in table as insert into test values (14 , 200,  28, 16, 'Q1431953')

Comment: Please suggest somting with insert the missing record by coverting primary to seconadary and vice versa

Comment: Thank you for ur quick response! You hardcoded the queue_id but i don't need hardcoded value as i need to run  it for huge data. kindly assist.

Comment: if I got your logic very well, my latest update will work for you.

Comment: Thanks you! Its working for me...awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You can generate the missing rows using `cross join` and then something like `left join` or `not exists`:

```
select sp.serial_id, sp.primary_id, sp.secondary_id
from (select d.serial_id, d.primary_id
      from data d
     ) sp join
     (select d.serial_id, d.secondary_id
      from data d
     ) ss
     on sp.serial_id = ss.serial_id left join
     data d
     on d.serial_id = sp.serial_id and
        d.primary_id = sp.primary_id and
        d.secondary_id = sp.secondary_id 
where d.serial_id is null;
```

You can then insert the results of this query into your table.

Your question doesn't specify what value of `queue_id` should be used.  `NULL` seems like a very reasonable value under these circumstances.

Comment: ifyou see the data carefully you will find primary id 8 has not the reverse records (primary become secondary and secondary become primary).one entry is missing so make entry for this like this: insert into test values (14, 200, 28 ,16 , 'Q1431953')